# Redirect to another page if stream is offline (PHP)

Tags: php

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 8000, $errno, $errstr, 1); //last param is timeout in seconds
if (!$fp) {
    header('Location: http://www.anothersite.com/some_message');
} else {
    fclose($fp); // radio OK
}
```

The code is not working and do not redirect.

Comment: There are many ways to make a redirect in PHP, HTML header or JavaScript. Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/768472) for instance.

Comment: Yes i saw these answers but they are not for a radio stream...

Comment: I don't understand how the fact that you're trying to open a radio stream is relevant. Just use `if (!$fp) { header('Location: '.$newURL); }`. Unless there's something obvious I'm missing...

Comment: tryed but not working :(

Comment: Normally you can not do a header redirect after you've sent output. So instead of the `echo error` line, do your redirect there, and on the landing page, show the viewer the stream is unavailable message. PS if you have changed your code, please edit your question to match what you currently have

Comment: I have changed my code for understanding what i try to do Thanks Duane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ob_start();
//something
ob_end_clean(); //erase output
header('Location: ');
```